# PHP Deprecated: round(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type int|float is deprecated in

Tags: magento2, php, deprecated

> PHP Deprecated:  round(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type
> int|float is deprecated in  "PREPAID_TAXABLE_AMOUNT"=>
> (($item->getDiscountAmount()) ? abs( round($item->getSubTotal(), 2) -
> round($item->getDiscountAmount(), 2) ) : '' )

I am getting this error in PHP 8 & Magento2.4

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem

```
"PREPAID_TAXABLE_AMOUNT"=> (($item->getDiscountAmount()) 
? abs( round((float) $item->getSubTotal(), 2) - round((float) $item->getDiscountAmount(), 2) ) 
: '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to fix the problem

```
"PREPAID_TAXABLE_AMOUNT"=> (
    ($item->getDiscountAmount() !== null) 
    ? abs(
        (is_numeric($item->getSubTotal()) ? round($item->getSubTotal(), 2) : 0)
        - (is_numeric($item->getDiscountAmount()) ? round($item->getDiscountAmount(), 2) : 0)
    )
    : ''
)
```